# MySQL strange behavior when using CURRENT_DATE minus numeric value

Tags: mysql, date

I encountered strange, unexpected behavior when using the CURRENT_DATE function in MySQL. Consider the following:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 0) AS 'today',
  DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 1) AS 'yesterday',
  DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 2) AS '2 days ago',
  DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 3) AS '3 days ago'
```

Strangely, this returns two dates and two NULL values (when executed on 2015-04-01). The following code returns four dates, as expected:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS 'today',
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS 'yesterday',
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -2 DAY) AS '2 days ago',
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -3 DAY) AS '3 days ago'
```

Anyone know why the former set of code returns unexpected results and the latter returns expected results?

Comment: So why do you think you can substract integers from a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for date and datetime "constants" are not dates and times.  They are either strings or numbers, as the documentation almost explains clearly:

> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD
>   format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or
>   numeric context.

The `-` creates a numeric context.  So,

```
DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 0) --> DATE(20150401 - 1) = DATE(20150401)
```

That gets converted correctly.  But consider:

```
DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 2) --> DATE(20150401 - 2) = DATE(20150399)
```

That is not a valid date.  So it is not converted.  Also, MySQL does recognize 20150400 as a date, which is why this is converted without an error.

When using MySQL, my recommendation is to use `date_add()` and `date_sub()` for all date manipulations, unless the date column is clearly typed as a date data type.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear and helpful. I'd vote up the answer but am just starting my account...so alas, I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Because CURRENT_DATE is date, not an integer. Consider the first query. What do you mean by -1? -1 second? minute? hour? day? month? year? How is MySQL supposed to guess that? Hence the existence of the INTERVAL statements

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In general when you subtract 1 from CURRENT_DATE it does indeed subtract one day. Since this is the default behavior and since I've seen this repeatedly, I came to expect it. The rationale you propose explains why the DATE_ADD approach is generally preferable (since I am forced to specify the INTERVAL as DAY), but it doesn't explain why in certain cases CURRENT_DATE - 1 returns NULL. The explanation below by @Gordon-Linoff clarifies that.